# How to setup Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking with PayPal using IPN (not PDT receipt page)?

Tags: paypal, google-analytics, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

I am trying to setup Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking. I appreciate this can relatively easily be done using PDT but I can't find any reference to using the IPN page to track the sales (which makes sense because a user never actually visits these). We use IPN to track the successful orders and it makes sense to tie the tracking in with this as this is the point that a successful order is flagged. We could in theory use PDT as well to track the sales but this will not contain all of the information for the transactions and (more importantly) the sale may not have actually completed when the PDT variables are passed back. To me this makes it much less desirable as it won't always be completely correct. Does anyone know of any way to use the ecommerce tracking via the IPN page instead, or is this not possible (or not sensible for another reason)?

Thanks so much as ever guys,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue. There could be a part of a solution, that could lose some transactions, by doing this:

- set a cookie on the user's browser just before he's redirected to Paypal (or on the final basket), when you set your Order ID.
- the user is sent to Paypal
- Paypal IPN is triggered
- user goes back to your website (one day, he will!)
- read the cookie you've set, on your «my account» pages for example, and if it matches an order:

  - Paypal status «Completed»: add the Google tracking code, using order ID, then delete the cookie
  - Paypal status not «Completed»: don't do anything

It's not 100% perfect, as some transactions may never be tracked, but at least it's the same user who executes the tracking code.